# Oracle update statement involving two tables (but not copying the data from the other table)

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle

This might be hard to explain, but I have two tables:

```
create table UserInputMovie
(
movid varchar2(7),
MUcomment varchar2(50),
MUname varchar2(25),
MUrating number(2)
);
```

and

```
create table TempMProfiles
(
movid varchar2(7),
mname varchar2(25),
mdesc varchar2(80)
);
```

What I want to do here is make it so that I can update `MUrating`, `MUcomment` where the `movid` of `TempMProfiles` is the same as `UserInputMovie`.

Comment: *where the movid of TempMProfiles is the same as the movid of UserInputMovie.*

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a `SELECT`, you need a `WHERE`-condition to find matching rows:

```
update UserInputMovie
set <whatever>
where exists
 (
   select * 
   from TempMProfiles  
   where TempMProfiles.movid  = UserInputMovie.movid
 )
```